# Return Local iPhone IP Address When on a VPN

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, ip, vpn

I need to be able to return an iOS device's local IP address when connected to a VPN. I am not worried about App Store compliance or using private frameworks.  I could only find sample code that returned either the cell network address or the wifi address but not the VPN address.

Answer (score 0):

Try here:

http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309927273/programmatically-retrieving-ip-address-of-iphone